# how to add domains to next.config.js for "next/image" while using a plugin

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-image

This is my current setup.

```js
// next.config.js
const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages({
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config;
  },
});
```

I want to add this code to allow images from the domain `localhost:3001`.

```
images: {
  domains: ['localhost:3001'],
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to add the `images` object to the config object passed to `withImages`.

```js
// next.config.js

const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages({
    images: {
        domains: ['localhost:3001']
    },
    webpack(config, options) {
        return config;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud set assetPrefix, read Options in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images)

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
  assetPrefix: 'https://example.com',
  dynamicAssetPrefix: true,
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
}
```