# Next.config.js Configuration with next-images

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-images

I would like to ask how can I use this piece of code.

> module.exports = {
> reactStrictMode: true,
> }

inside this code block:

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
  assetPrefix: 'https://example.com',
  dynamicAssetPrefix: true,
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```

Comment: Depending on your version of next, it already supports importing images: [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [how to add domains to next.config.js for "next/image" while using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896774/how-to-add-domains-to-next-config-js-for-next-image-while-using-a-plugin)? Just add `reactStrictMode: true` to the object you're passing to `withImages`.