# How to use next-images alongside rewrite in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have used rewrite in my next.config.js to add a proxy to my requests, But I also want to use next-images to be able to load svg files but I'm not sure how can I use that alongside rewrite in next.config.js

```
const API_SERVER_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000';

const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `${API_SERVER_ENDPOINT}/api/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Here I don't know how I can also add withImages in module.exports, Please help

Comment: What is the problem here? Have you tried wrapping your Next.js config with `withImages` as the docs suggest. Also do you have any specific reason to use `next-images` at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [how to add domains to next.config.js for “next/image” while using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66903879/1870780)? Simply pass the config object to the `withImages` call, e.g., `withImages({ /* your config here */})`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap config with `withImages`

```
const API_SERVER_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000';

const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages({
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `${API_SERVER_ENDPOINT}/api/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
});
```