# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' Need appropriate loader

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, config

I tried using google spreadsheet npm package for connecting my form present in a Next JS app to google sheets. I faced an issue where the error was as given below:

`error - ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:17:0`
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'`
`null`

I solved it by changing my next.config.js from

`const withImages = require('next-images');`

`module.exports = { ...withImages(), trailingSlash: true };`

to

```
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = {
    ...withImages(),
    trailingSlash: true,
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.node = {
            fs: 'empty',
            child_process: 'empty',
            net: 'empty',
            dns: 'empty',
            tls: 'empty'
        };
        return config;
    }
};
```

But after the change I get a new error as:

`error - ./src/assets/images/logo/logo.png 1:0`
`Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)`
`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`
`(Source code omitted for this binary file)`

Is there any way to correct this?

PS: I use type script for the coding part.

Comment: Does this answer your question [how to add domains to next.config.js for "next/image" while using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66903879/1870780)? You should nest the config object inside the `withImages()` call.

Comment: Was it something that simple? I am kinda embarssed.